# Multiple if statements with else for get_the_category

Tags: categories, attachments, conditional-tags, php

I created some code to return attachment categories, that looks like:

```
<?php
    // Attachment Categories
    $categories = get_the_category($attachment->ID);
    if ($categories) {
?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
            <?php if ($category->name !== 'Slides') if ($category->name !== 'Uncategorized') { ?>
                <li><?php echo $category->name; ?></li>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

I am trying to add an `else`, but for some reason the else doesn't work with the two `if` statements...if I remove one `if` statement, the `else` works.

The code with the `else` looks like:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <?php if ($category->name !== 'Slides') if ($category->name !== 'Uncategorized') { ?>
            <li><?php echo $category->name; ?></li>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <li>Unknown</li>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: why you are not using [operators](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp) but two ifs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you chain multiple conditions with an `if` statement.  Try this

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <?php if ($category->name !== 'Slides' && $category->name !== 'Uncategorized') { ?>
            <li><?php echo $category->name; ?></li>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <li>Unknown</li>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is a great answer, unfortunately Sanjeev submitted a response first, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Timing says mine was first, not really worried about though.

Comment: You're right, my apologies, I've updated my selection :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <?php if ($category->name !== 'Slides' && $category->name !== 'Uncategorized') { ?>
            <li><?php echo $category->name; ?></li>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <li>Unknown</li>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Bro use && or || Operator according to your requirement as i wrote above.